# memcpy optimization in cortex-a8 arm

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

i use memcpy() in my implementation on ARM Cortex a8,
it is my first code to develop on ARM Processors.

i read in the following link that i can optimize performance through some strategies.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13544.html

my code says

```
  ..
  memcpy(myvar1, myvar2, myvar_size * sizeof(var_complex));
  ..
```

how can i optimize this code for ARM Cortex-a8 using Eclipse GCC Toolchain.
my code contains both C and Assembly codes.
is that affects using some registers ?
i searched for some examples and didn't found.

Comment: The first thing to do is benchmark it, and see if you're spending (too) much time in `memcpy()` to begin with. If you do, then check what the standard library's implementation is, it probably already is trying to be optimized.